# htaccess redirect to another URL - possible?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website, lets call it http://www.example.com. On that website I am displaying links to another website. The links look like that:

```
http://anotherwebsite.com/?pid=12&wmid=567&cpid=2&prid=20&target=Suche_Deeplink_Expose&attr1=12345678
```

The only param that changes is `attr1`. Now, on my example.com site, I want to have a link like http://www.example.com/?attr1=12345678 and when the user clicks the link it should redirect to http://anotherwebsite.com/?pid=12&wmid=567&cpid=2&prid=20&target=Suche_Deeplink_Expose&attr1=12345678.

Can that be done with htaccess?

Thanks!

**This solved it:** [Display link on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898005/display-link-on-mouseover)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Redirect 301. It's pretty easy.

Redirect 301 {Current Site} {New Site}

Parameters can be passed and rewritten.

You can read about it here:
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess

Comment: Even if the links are dynamic?

Comment: I solved it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898005/display-link-on-mouseover

Comment: Your question was if it can be done over htaccess and this can do that if you know how to use regex to rewrite the url to what you want.